# Округление абсолютного значения

Tags: java

Как можно округлить число в зависимости от абсолютно значения?
Т.е. что бы, например, 1.6 округлялось до 2, а -1.6 до -2.

Comment: я Вам настоятельно рекомендую такие элементарные вопросы гуглить, ибо гугл наше все

Answer (score 1):

Документация для JavaScript. Элементарно

[Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: вопрос был про java =)

Comment: http://proglang.su/java/numbers-round